# arrayList<MyClass> does not save the value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm developing an app and have the following problem.
Download data from my server and come in a string of the form data1, data2, data3; ...

With the split function I separate and I put every thing into a string [] and then using the gettet and setter of my parameterized class add an object of that class. Finally I make an ArrayList <> my class you add all object.

The problem is that when I utlizo the ArrayList <> the asistencia of my class field is initialized to 0 and it did not copy the actual data.

I put the code and log cat.

Thanks for your time and help.

```
result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

String[] aux1 = result.split(":");  

for (int i =0; i< aux1.length; i++)
{
        Servicio servAux = new Servicio();
        String[] aux = aux1[i].split(";");  

        servAux.setTipo(Integer.parseInt(aux[0]));
        servAux.setNombre(aux[1]);
        servAux.setDescripcion(aux[2]);
        servAux.setHora(aux[3]);
        servAux.setMinuto(aux[4]);
        servAux.setLugar(aux[5]);
        servAux.setDuracion(aux[6]);
        servAux.setFecha(aux[7]);
        servAux.setHoraCero(aux[8]);
        servAux.setId(Integer.parseInt(aux[9]));
        for (int j=0; j<serviciosSi.size();j++)
        {
                if (servAux.getId() == serviciosSi.get(j))
                {
                    servAux.setAsistencia(1);
                    Log.i("result","en servicio: "+servAux.getId()+" pongo asistencia: "+servAux.getAsistencia());
                }

                else
                    servAux.setAsistencia(0);
        }
        listaServicios.add(servAux);
}
for(int j =0; j<listaServicios.size();j++)
{
         Log.i("result","listaServicios-> id: "+listaServicios.get(j).getId()+"  asist: "+listaServicios.get(j).getAsistencia());
}
```

I put the declaration of ArrayList, is a global variable of the class of acitivty

```
public class Inicio extends Activity 
{
    ArrayList<Servicio> listaServicios = new ArrayList<Servicio>();
    ...
```

And the log cat:

```
en servicio: 7 pongo asistencia: 1
en servicio: 4 pongo asistencia: 1
en servicio: 3 pongo asistencia: 1
en servicio: 6 pongo asistencia: 1
listaServicios-> id: 7  asist: 1
listaServicios-> id: 1  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 4  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 3  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 6  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 5  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 2  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 0  asist: 0
listaServicios-> id: 8  asist: 0
```

**if you look puts the object of the parameterized class that id 7 4 6 3 have asistencia 1 but when one travels the ArrayList <> id only seven have asistencia 1**

Comment: Feels more like a debugging issue to me, and this is not an MCVE either, it's actually pretty hard to read.

Comment: I think the problem is in this `if (servAux.getId() == serviciosSi.get(j))` but you should provide the code of what is serviciosSi is actually!

Comment: add a `break` statement into the `if (servAux.getId() == serviciosSi.get(j))` block to exit the `for` loop if you've found a mathing id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the order of your program.

```
for (int j=0; j<serviciosSi.size();j++)
    {
            if (servAux.getId() == serviciosSi.get(j))
            {
                servAux.setAsistencia(1);
                Log.i("result","en servicio: "+servAux.getId()+" pongo asistencia: "+servAux.getAsistencia());
            }

            else
                servAux.setAsistencia(0);
    }
    listaServicios.add(servAux);
```

So if in the last iteration of the loop, it comes into the else path, asistencia will be set to 0, what does not happen in your log statement, because this is called in the if statement and not after the loop.